# Forwarding X11 between Windows > Linux Server1 > Linux server2

Tags: linux, forwarding, x11

I got this problem...

My machine is a Windows(S1), who needs to connect to a Linux Server(S2) [used like a jumpbox], to connect with Linux Server(S3), which is the target machine.

I got Putty and Xming well configured, since I can open Firefox browser on S2; but when I connect to the S3 via SSH I can't open any X app there. I installed the xclock so I can test it, and I got this message:

Error: Can't open display

My proceedure is: Windows >putty> LinuxS2 >SSH> LinuxS3.
Can open X apps on Linux S2, but not on Linux S3.

The networks between Windows and Linux S3 are differente, that's why the Linux S2 exists.

Comment: You can do the equivalent of the *nix `ProxyCommand` in putty just where you multiple links chained together.  In doing this you can make your client act as if you are directly connecting to the far host.  http://mikelococo.com/2008/01/multihop-ssh/ https://superuser.com/a/949779/2057

Comment: Do you connect with **-X** from s2 to s3?

Comment: Yes, I always connect like: ssh -X user@Ip

I don't know what to do... on the first server I can open Firefox, but when I connect to the target, I can't open the xclock.

Already checked everything, and even so I can't do it =/


Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In your Putty session:

1) you need to enable Connection => SSH => X11 Forwarding

2) invoke ssh to S3 with -X option in Connection => SSH => Remote Command , for example : ssh -X user@S3

In S2 and S3, the /etc/ssh/sshd_config  need to have X11Forwarding set to yes.
(restart sshd when changing this).

The DISPLAY should be set to a value starting from value of X11DisplayOffset in sshd_config of S3.

And hopefully, this should make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I got everything configured like you said... but I don't get the last step very well...

What I need to do with DISPLAY?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, you don't need to do anything with DISPLAY except checking it is given a value: "echo $DISPLAY" should show something like "10:0". If it is empty, this means some stuff is missing. Did you get it working?

Comment: No, not yet...
And i got everything configured like you said.

When I enter echo $DISPLAY nothing happens on LinuxS3 =S

Comment: This means for some reason the X11Forwarding is not enabled.

Comment: 1) check $DISPLAY on intermediate server S2 with a ssh (putty with X11 forwarding option but ithout the second ssh command in). Echo $DISPLAY should show something there.

2) on your server S3, check the sshd log (set LogLevel VERBOSE in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and look in syslog )

3) maybe you could post your sshd_config: 

grep -v -E '^\s*#|^\s*$' /etc/ssh/sshd_config